# Css no reconoce las clases que tengo en HTML en VSCode

Tags: html, css, vscode

Ayuda por favor, Tengo la duda en Visual Studio Code si Existe algún plugin para VSCode para que en css reconozca las clases de Html(Autocomplete), porque por defecto no las hace, no reconoce las clases que tengo en html y tengo que estar escribiendo las clases a mano y seria mucho mejor que reconociera las clases que ya tengo en html.
Ojala me puedan ayudar y pasar el plugin o alguna configuración de VSCode para hacer eso.
Les agradecería mucho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para que te sugieran las clases que ya tienes creadas en HTML en el CSS:

```
zitup.classnametocss
```

Y para que en el HTML te sugiera lo que tienes en el CSS:

```
zignd.html-css-class-completion
```

Para descargarlo, abre el Visual Studio y haz clic en Extensiones y en el buscador escribe lo comentado arriba.

Comment: Amigo sigue sin sugerirme las clases que tengo html, creo que ese plugin es para otro tipo de archivos. O algo asi vi en su demo. No tienes otro plugin.?. El segundo si me funciona pero el primero no o hay que activarlo o como se hace.?

Comment: Yo justo probé ```zitup.classnametocss``` y me funcionaba perfecto como tu querias. Hacías un ```<div class="prueba"> </div>``` y en el css al escribir . Ya te sugería la clase prueba para autocompletar.

Comment: Pues que raro en el mio no funciono pero probe otro plugin el cual lo hizo: 'HTML to CSS autocompletion' Ese es el nombre y funciono perfectamente de todas formas gracias, no se si tengas algun plugin para javascript esque aveces en el VScode no me ayuda con el autocompletado te doy un ejemplo al poner este codigo:

Comment: const selectElement = (element) => document.querySelector(element);
selectElement('.container').addEventList.....         ======El addEventListener no me lo auto-completa osea no me sugiere nada, y es molesto estar escribiendo el nombre completo no se tengas algún plugin para eso o alguna configuración para que siempre me de sugerencias.

Comment: @DanielReyes En extensiones de VSCode pon algo como ```javascript complete``` o autocomplete y te saldrán montones de extensiones para lo que quieres. Así que tendrás que buscar y probarlas.

Answer (score 0):

Si entendí bien tu pregunta.Tu deberías tener tu clase en html asi :

```
<div class="Login">
  //contenido
</div>
```

ahora hay tres formas de agregar estilos a un html:

1.En un archivo externo.

En tu archivo .htm dentro de la etiqueta Head debemos poner la etiqueta link para enlazar con nuestro archivo .css externo

```
<link href=”ruta absoluta o ruta relativa”></link>
```

tu código en css así en un archivo tuarchivo.css :

```
   .Login {
        //propiedades css
    }
```

2. en un encabezado dentro de `<head>`:

`<head>
     <style>
      body{
       background-color: #ffffff
      }
      </style>
</head>`

3.embebido en la propia etiqueta html

```
<a style="color:red"></a>
```

Comment: Lo que quiero esque en mi archivo css ya vinculado previamente en el Html, me sugiera las clases que tengo escritas en html, como me explico que me ayude con el autocompletado eso es lo que quiero ya que me quita tiempo estas escribiendo letra a letra las clases.

Answer (score 0):

Esta es una extensión que encontré que hace exactamente lo que tu necesitas. Puedes leer la documentación en GitHub y probarla.

[ecmel/vscode-html-css](https://github.com/ecmel/vscode-html-css)

En caso de que estes trabajando con scss puedes revisar esta otra extensión.

[HTML SCSS Support](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=P-de-Jong.vscode-html-scss)

Hasta ahora el único inconveniente que he encontrado con las anteriores extensiones es que necesitas guardar los cambios en tu archivo .css para que se reconozca en tu archivo .html

Ahora, esta otra extensión te autocompleta de una manera diferente. Según la documentación que puedes encontrar aquí: [All Autocomplete](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Atishay-Jain.All-Autocomplete), el autocompletado se basa en todos los editores abiertos que tengas en VSCode, y te muestra sugerencias de clases, variables etc., asi que hay que tener cuidado.